# How can I find an extension on MS Edge Add-ons store or the full URL of the extension using a CRX ID ? (CRX ID is 32-characters long keyword)

Tags: microsoft-edge, browser-extension, microsoft-edge-extension, browser-addons, microsoft-edge-chromium

I have the CRX ID of a Microsoft Edge extension. How can I find the extension on MS Edge Add-ons store using this CRX ID or the full URL of the extension?

Answer (score 0):

Here, I am assuming that you are searching for an already published extension.

By default, we can search the extension by typing its name in the search box on [MS Edge Add-ons store](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/Microsoft-Edge-Extensions-Home).

[image]

I made some tests with the Add-ons store site and found that we can find the specific extension by passing the extension ID with the URL.

We can see the extension ID(32 characters long) of an installed extension by visiting the `edge://extensions/` page in the MS Edge browser.

URL syntax would be below.

`https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/<Modify_extension_id_here>?hl=en-US`

You need to replace the `<Modify_extension_id_here>` with the actual `extension-ID` in the URL above will open that extension page.

Let me know if you have further questions.

Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Pick any store URL, replace the last 32 digits (CRX ID) with the new CRX ID and run it in the browser to get the full URL as the page refreshes.

For example to find the URL for this CRX ID: **ghbhpcookfemncgoinjblecnilppimih**

Go to any store product detail page for example https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/microsoft-editor-spellin/hokifickgkhplphjiodbggjmoafhignh ; change the CRX ID to **ghbhpcookfemncgoinjblecnilppimih** and you will see it resolves to https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/accessibility-insights-fo/ghbhpcookfemncgoinjblecnilppimih

Let me know if this was helpful. I am happy to help you with more details.